# Underlying type of a mock object

Tags: .net, mocking, moq

I need to check the type of a mock object and want to get the underlying type. For instance, for an object such as Mock is there anything on here I can call to get the type, "Foo"? I am using moq.

```
Mock<Foo> myFoo = new Mock<Foo>
myFoo.Object.?
myFoo.?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Type t = myFoo.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First();
```

Comment: Is there anything that will work on the object? I want to pass in a Func to a method that takes an object of type Foo so it would be a little more convenient to do it that way?

Comment: Mock.Get(obj) will return the mock object for the instance.

Comment: This answer got me there.  This is what I had to do to get the underlying type of a moq object though:
((System.RuntimeType)vehicleDTOs.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]).FullName